# Passing Parameters Using Rails 4 date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Below in is the HTML5 output I am looking for. The Goal is to pass a parameter from the dropdown calendar to my controller and refresh the page with the input selected.

```
<form action="/cats/<%=@cats.number_id %>">
    <input type="date" name="as_of_date" id="as_of_date" value="<%= Time.parse(@as_of).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Re-calculate">
</form>
```

I noticed that format of the date_field helper is this according to http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/date_field :

```
@user.born_on = Date.new(1984, 1, 27)
date_field("user", "born_on", value: "1984-05-12")
# => <input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="date" value="1984-05-12" />
```

Beyond this point I do not know how to effectively use the date_field helper.

Comment: Hi Nick, is it safe to assume that you are completely inexperienced in Rails?

Comment: @Raffael I am learning slowly.

Comment: Consider checking out Rails for Zombies. They have good beginner's tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you would typically use a `form_for` helper to generate a form. Inside that form you can then use a `date_field` helper, like so:

```
<%= form_for @cat do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :as_of_date %>
  <%= f.submit 'Re-calculate' %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, you would initialize `@cat` as an instance of an `ActiveRecord` model named `Cat`. This will not generate exactly what you asked for, but hopefully close enough:

```
<form class="edit_cat" id="edit_cat_89" action="/cats/89" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="kdCpL...wEDA==">
    <input value="2015-10-13" type="date" name="cat[as_of_date]" id="cat_as_of_date">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Re-calculate">
</form>
```

If the date is not a cat's attribute, you might want to use something like this:

```
<%= form_for "/cats/#{cat_id}" do |f| %>
  <%= date_field_tag :as_of_date, Date.new(2015, 10, 13) %>
  <%= f.submit 'Re-calculate' %>
<% end %>
```

HTH!